# How can i highlight the Kendo grid cell by color change after update

Tags: kendo-ui, signalr, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using Kendo Ui Grid with MVC and SignalR. I can successfully perform the CRUD operations on grid using SignalR. I would like to notify clients by highlighting(By changing cell color) the updated cell. How can I achieve this with the following code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Webapplication1.Models.ShipViewModel>()
.Name("ShipGrid")
.Columns(c =>{
    c.Bound(m => m.Id).Hidden();
    c.Bound(m => m.LocationViewModel)
        .Title("Location1");
    c.Bound(m => m.Location2ViewModel)
        .Title("Location2");
    c.Bound(m => m.boxSent);
    c.Command(p =>
    {
        p.Edit().Text(" ").UpdateText(" ").CancelText(" ");
        p.Destroy().Text(" ").HtmlAttributes(new { @title = "Cancel" });
    });
})
.ToolBar(toolbar =>
{
    toolbar.Create().Text("").HtmlAttributes(new { @title = "Add" });
})
.Editable(editable => editable
    .DisplayDeleteConfirmation("DELETE.")
    .Mode(Kendo.Mvc.UI.GridEditMode.PopUp)
    .TemplateName("abcEditor")
    )
.Events(events =>
{
    events.Edit("edit");
}) 
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource 
    .SignalR()        
    .Transport(tr => tr
        .Promise("hubStart")
        .Hub("mainHub")
        .Client(c => c.Read("abc_Read").Create("abc_Insert").Update("abc_Update").Destroy("abc_Delete"))
        .Server(s => s.Read("abc_Read").Create("abc_Insert").Update("abc_Update").Destroy("abc_Delete")))
  .Schema(schema => schema  
    .Model(m => {
        m.Id(p => p.Id);
        m.Field(p => p.Location1ViewModel).DefaultValue(ViewData["DefaultLocation1"] as Webapplication1.Models.Location1ViewModel);
        m.Field(p => p.Location2ViewModel).DefaultValue(ViewData["DefaultLocation2"] as Webapplication1.Models.DeliveryLocationViewModel);
    })
 )
)
```

)

I would like to Highlight the cell that is being updating here. Something like stock market data flashing. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have achieved this as below and its working fine:

in my .cshtml page

```
myHub.client.highlightRow = function (id) {
        var data = $("#MyGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var dataItem = data[i];
            if (dataItem.id == id) {
                //alert(dataItem.uid);
                $("#MyGrid").data("kendoGrid").tbody.find("tr[data-uid=" + dataItem.uid + "]").effect("highlight", { color: "#f35800" }, 3000);
            }
        }
    };
```

And in my update/insert method in my SignalR Hub class:

```
Clients.Others.highlightRow(mygridViewModel.Id);
```

Answer (score 3):

I've done similar kind of thing. I don't know if that helps you. In your default view model add a extra property, say "Updated" as a boolean. Now every time you have update a row, put "Updated" as a true.

And in kendo grid add a new dataBound event.

```
.Events(events => events.DataBound("onDataBound"))
```

Now on JS use something like the following;

```
function onDataBound(arg) {

    var itemsInActivityGrid = $("#ShippingGrid").data().kendoGrid.dataSource.data().length;

    for (i = 0; i < itemsInActivityGrid; i++) {
        if ($("#ShippingGrid").data().kendoGrid.dataSource.data()[i].Updated == true) {
            $("#ShippingGrid .k-grid-content tr[data-uid='" + $("#ShippingGrid").data().kendoGrid.dataSource.data()[i].uid + "']").css("background-color", "orange");
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:** I don't know your logic. As far as you put on comments, you want to do something like online share dealing sites. Anyway, as far as I could, if you want to highlight individual cell in a row, add another extra field say "Column" along with "Updated"; it could be a string. Here you mark which cell you want to put the back ground colour from the backend. Say we've got it's value as "2".

```
for (i = 0; i < itemsInActivityGrid; i++) 
{
    var TableUID = $("#ShippingGrid").data().kendoGrid.dataSource.data()[i].uid;

    var TableToColour = $("#ShippingGrid .k-grid-content tr[data-uid='" + TableUID + "']").parent().parent()[0];

    var ColumnToColor = $("#ShippingGrid").data().kendoGrid.dataSource.data()[i].Column;

    $(TableToColour.rows[0].cells[" + ColumnToColor + "]).select().attr("style","background-color:blue")
}
```

In case, you need to highlight multiple cells on the same row, in Column send something like "1,2,3,5"; where 1, 2, 3 and 5 represents the column numbers on the same row. And after ColumnToColor do some string parsing, put it into a for loop or something and colour;

Hope this helps. Thank you.

Comment: I think This would change the background color of the row but i want just to notify by flashing the changed color of the upadated row like stock market data changing.

Comment: Thanks Mahib. Desperately waiting for your response.

Comment: Sorry for the delay mate. Hope this helps now.

Comment: Hi Mahib, i have tried this but it's not working for me. May be because of SignalR, OnDatabound event(AJAX) is not firing or may be i am not understanding it properly. Anyway I have achieved it simply by jquery. I have posted my answer here.